# Will script continue if what it checks for changes?

Tags: scripts, suspend, ubuntu-mate

I have a question about this.
I have it as a startup program.

If a download ends or I delete .part files, will the script then suspend?

```
 for file in /home/andy/Downloads/*.part ; do
        if [[ -f $file ]]; then
            echo "File download in progress."
            echo "Computer can not suspend until download is complete."
            echo "Now exiting."
            sleep 2 
            break
        fi
    done

    echo "This script will suspend computer in 5 minutes if there is no mouse or keyboard activity."
    while :; do
      if (( $(xprintidle) >= 300000 )); then
        systemctl suspend
    fi
      sleep 0.5
    done
```

---

3/26/19 6:00 pm I tried code based on Sergiy's answer and got an error:

```
line 5: [: too many arguments
```

Code

```
#!/bin/bash
old=$(du -sh /home/andy/Downloads/myfile.iso)
while true; do
    new=$(du -sh /home/andy/Downloads/myfile.iso)
    if [ $old -eq $new  ] ; 
    then
        break
    fi
    old=$new
    xdotool getactivewindow key Ctrl
    sleep 5
done

line 5: [: too many arguments
```

Comment: Just FYI  edits which include error messages and non-working code should be posted into the question, not the answer.

Comment: The quoted ` [ "$old" -eq "$new"  ]` should fix the error. I'll try to polish the code a little bit, and will update my answer once I do that

Answer (score 0):

The script will still allow for computer to suspend, because the `for` loop is not sending any signal to the GUI and is not generating GUI events.

What I do sometimes is find the file that I am downloading and monitor if its size is changing, while at the same time issuing Ctrl key press event with `xdotool`. In other words, this could be something like

```
old=$(du -sh ~/Downloads/myfile.iso)
while true; do
    new=$(du -sh ~/Downloads/myfile.iso)
    if [ $old -eq $new  ] ; then
        break
    fi
    old=$new
    xdotool getactivewindow key Ctrl
    sleep 5
done
```

As for the second loop in your script, it is alright.

Comment: But would I not have to manually change the file name for each download? @Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy

Comment: @fixit7 Yes, it would be better and more precise that way. Remind me of this answer at some point later, I'll update it

Comment: ok.@Seriy Kolodyazhnyy I did think of maybe one way. Get a list of .part files and pass them on to the script?